# Issue with dynamic content load in jQuery

Tags: jquery, getjson, replacewith

I have div in HTML and replacing content with replaceWith after getting html file with $.get but it is loading twice. Can somebody tell why it happening

```
$.get("http://example.com/file.html", function(data) {
      $('script').each(function() {
        $(this).remove()
      })
      $('#wiki').replaceWith(data)
    })
```

If the same page load without refresh then all code under document ready will run more than once. So I start debugging and I found out browser is keeping same virtually files and then running them due to that it running twice

[image]

Comment: Removing a script tag in document doesn't remove the compiled code. Explain your issue in more detail

Comment: My issue is that I have i div where I am replacing html content by getting from external html file, first time it runs as expected but second time again runs code than previous file which is still in the memory and new file I call

Comment: @charlietfl, you are correct Removing a script tag in document doesn't remove the compiled code. So what is the way to remove code and don't run twice

Comment: If all you want is the content you can extract it from `data`. Is that what you want?

Comment: @charlietfl Point is that I am loading html file which have html and JavaScript. First time when I loaf file all works but second time when i load previous load javascript is still in the memory and new load javascript run

Comment: Not clear if you need the new script to run or not....or just extract raw html content. Can parse the response for content only if that's what you want

Comment: @charlietfl Point is that I am loading html file which have html and JavaScript. First time when I loaf file all works but second time when i load previous load javascript is still in the memory and new load javascript. So both run and make issue

Comment: @charlietfl So I can we nullify memory loaded script and always run freshly loaded script

Comment: No...that's not possible. What is this code doing? Provide example. If it is event listeners those can be delegated and only extract the actual part of content needed in ajax response (without script). Not enough known.

Comment: There 2 html files with javascript and I loading those files i div on certain events but it always run code if that html file was loaded previously

Comment: You are not answering my questions. Show samples as per [mcve]. One possible choice is only insert non script content extracted from `data` in request. The other is rewrite script. Still not enough known about what your script is doing

Comment: Ok let create codepen and get back to you